# How to know which stored procedure has cross database query

Tags: sql-server, database

I want to know which stored procedure has cross database/ linked server call.

I know i can do some kind string search with database name being string to search. 
One of the example of it as below

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       o.name AS Object_Name,
       o.type_desc
  FROM sys.sql_modules m
       INNER JOIN
       sys.objects o
         ON m.object_id = o.object_id
 WHERE m.definition Like '%{{DBNAME}}%';
```

but if possible then i do not want to go for string search so is there any other way to find all procedure which might have cross database/ linked server ?

Comment: Have you tried it with the SQL Server Profiler tool?

Answer (score 1):

There is a system view `sys.sql_expression_dependencies` that provides exactly this information:

```
select d.*
from sys.sql_expression_dependencies d
where d.referenced_database_name is not null
    and d.is_ambiguous = 0;
```

Pay attention, however, that some of the references might be "fake", or rather not what you expect. For example, XML methods are also listed in it, which might cause some confusion.